# What solutions are available for using iPad as an extended desktop?

Tags: ipad, display

Occasionally, I would like to use my iPad (3rd gen, iOS7) as a second screen (an extension, NOT a mirror) for my Macbook Pro (Mountain Lion).

Is this possible without paying for an app in iOS7? Does Mavericks or iOS7 include any new related functionality? I am aware that there have been improvements for second displays in Mavericks.

See also: [How to use the new iPad (3rd gen) as a second screen?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46077/how-to-use-the-new-ipad-3rd-gen-as-a-second-screen?rq=1) and [Is it possible to use an iPad as an additional computer monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/is-it-possible-to-use-an-ipad-as-an-additional-computer-monitor?rq=1)

Comment: *Without* paying for an app?

Comment: @timothymh yes, I wondered if iOS7 / Mavericks had changed things as new OS releases often incorporate functionality previously only available through third-party apps. I've updated my question to better reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an app to get this working properly, the nice new features in Mavericks are still essentially limited to traditionally connected displays via cables (DisplayPort/HDMI/Thunderbolt), rather than wireless connections.  There are many you can try, but [my (unaffiliated merely personal preference) recommendation is Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display).

Note that because the 2nd screen will be transferred over Wifi, you need to ensure that the iPad has a solid connection to the same LAN as your main Mac - being close to your Mac might be no good if they are both a distance away from the router...  As such, any usage of the iPad 2nd screen that requires fast refresh of window contents might not perform in any way like a proper monitor would, but it should be great for normal non video/gaming OS X apps.

Comment: (This isn't arguing or anything; I'm merely presenting data.) Air Display ($10) has 3 stars on the iOS App Store. The only other alternatives I've found (for Mac) are iDisplay ($5), also with 3 stars, and DisplayPad ($3), with 5 stars. Be aware, though, that certain graphics cards are incompatible with DisplayPad.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Mavericks does not include this kind of features.

Yes you'll need to use 3rd party apps.

Answer (score 0):

check out Splashtop if you haven't yet.  I think you'll pay a small amount for the iPad app, but the Mac app is free and also works for remote connections.