# Extend Mac display to Windows 10

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, display, windows

is there an app to extend a MacBook Pro early 2016 display (OS X El Capitan 10.11.5) to a Windows 10 laptop? Preferably free, by the way, and also not counting Air Display since the newest version doesn't work on Windows.

**The goal is this: just like you could extend the display of a Mac to a monitor using Thunderbolt, I would like to extend it to a Windows 10 screen using some software**

So far, I have looked into multiple apps, such as AirDisplay, Splashtop, WIDisplay, Synergy, and ScreenRecycler as mentioned by bwall's answer.

Comment: I am not understanding what you want to do here.  Can you clarify what you are looking to accomplish and what research you have done thus far?

Comment: So far I have looked into multiple apps, such as AirDisplay, Splashtop, WIDisplay, Synergy, and ScreenRecycler as mentioned by bwall's answer. The goal is this: just like you could extend the display of a Mac to a monitor using Thunderbolt, I would like to extend it to a Windows 10 screen using some software.

Comment: Ok, great.  I added that info to the question so the question itself is much clearer.  It's best to post this information upfront so the question isn't so open ended.  The more info we have, the better.

Comment: I agree, the edit looks great.

Comment: It's worth noting that both android devices and iOS devcies can be used as second monitors as well: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/is-it-possible-to-use-an-ipad-as-an-additional-computer-monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it will work. It's not free, but I haven't seen anything else that works. It uses a VNC client for the "other" computer, but it says any VNC client should work so you don't have to buy theirs. You only have to buy the Mac program. There are plenty of free VNC clients for Windows. There's a free trial so you can download it and see if it works.

https://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html

Comment: ScreenRecycler demo only appears to last for 20 minutes, but it looks good thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found [Avatron Software](https://sites.fastspring.com/avatron/product/airdisplayforwindows) that works on both Mac and PC hosts and will extend your display to iOS, Android, Windows and Mac devices.

The software isn't free ($20), but they have a free trial.  I downloaded a copy this morning and I am currently testing it out.  So far, it installed with no problem and I extended my iMac display to it quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I had reasonable success using [airserver](https://www.airserver.com/) which can make a windows laptop behave like a airplay device (and a chromecast device, and a miracast device). This feels like quite a nice "standards-based approach" in that it uses protocol.

I could then set the airplay device in the "displays" sections of settings to this device. I needed to tweak the firewall rules to allow inbound connections to built-in services for this to work as outlined [here](https://www.chriswrites.com/fix-common-airplay-connection-problems/).

airserver has a 30 day trial and then charges money. There is also a free program called 5Kdisplay, which also implement airplay, but the display resolution is rubbish.

I would kind of prefer to do something over USB, the refresh rate was a little low over airplay for me. I ended up using my phone as a hub when I didn't have access to a network. I wonder if you could make a usb cable provide a virtual network connection for two devices.